# The image of the function $f$ is ____________?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $ f(x) =  \tan^{-1} \exp(-x-x^{-1})$  on  $x >0$,the  image of the   function $f$  is ____________?

My try :$ f(x) =  \tan^{-1} \exp(-x-x^{-1}) = tan^{-1} e^{ -(x^2 +1)/x}$

If $x$ tend to $ \infty$ then  $\tan^{-1} 0 = \pi$

that  mean image  of function  will open

Comment: It is asking what is the set of all values: $\{f(x)| x>0\}$

Comment: okss ,thanks U @saulspatz

Comment: the image of the function $f$ is *beautiful*!

Comment: im not getting @WhatsUp

Comment: Sorry for the bad joke... I was using the word "image" in the sense of e.g. images.google.com . Of course putting a _________ in the question is very ambiguous (yet often appears in exams), as you were also confused by what it was exactly asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $f(x)=\tan^{-1}\exp{-(\dfrac{1}{x}+x)}$. Then $$\dfrac{1}{x}+x\geqslant2\implies -(\dfrac{1}{x}+x)\leqslant-2\implies \exp{-(\dfrac{1}{x}+x)}\leqslant \mathrm{e}^{-2}\implies f(x)\leqslant \tan^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{-2}).$$
Just use the monotonicity of $\exp(\cdot)$ and $\tan^{-1}(\cdot)$.